# Identify 22-TET intervals

Tags: code-golf, music

## Objective

Given the distance between two keys in an octave, identify its name.

But there's a caveat. In this challenge, there are [22](https://en.xen.wiki/w/22edo) keys in an octave, not usual 12.

Here, a [porcupine[7] scale](https://en.xen.wiki/w/Porcupine) will be assumed.

## Mapping

White keys are marked **bold**.

| Distance | Name |
| --- | --- |
| **0** | `Unison` |
| 1 | `Augmented Unison` or `Diminished Second` |
| 2 | `Minor Second` |
| **3** | `Major Second` |
| 4 | `Augmented Second` |
| 5 | `Diminished Third` |
| **6** | `Minor Third` |
| 7 | `Major Third` |
| 8 | `Augmented Third` or `Diminished Fourth` |
| **9** | `Perfect Fourth` |
| 10 | `Major Fourth` |
| 11 | `Augmented Fourth` or `Diminished Fifth` |
| 12 | `Minor Fifth` |
| **13** | `Perfect Fifth` |
| 14 | `Augmented Fifth` or `Diminished Sixth` |
| 15 | `Minor Sixth` |
| **16** | `Major Sixth` |
| 17 | `Augmented Sixth` |
| 18 | `Diminished Seventh` |
| **19** | `Minor Seventh` |
| 20 | `Major Seventh` |
| 21 | `Augmented Seventh` or `Diminished Octave` |
| *(others)* | *(don't care)* |

## Rule

You can freely mix cases in output. Trailing whitespaces are permitted.

Comment: Please provide some test cases.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin The "Mapping" presents all test cases.

Comment: Do you confirm it's OK to use either the augmented or diminished form in an inconsistent way when both are allowed? (Sorry, I should have asked before answering.)

Comment: @Arnauld It's a free choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 54 bytes

```
6ɾ›∆o`diø¤Ṁ§ ↑ṙ €ǐ ÷¨ «ø⟑ƒ₄ḭ`⌈vMƒJRvṄ»9Tr⌈»bTİ`Ẏ↲½Ŀ`pi
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIyMihu4oC5OuKCtGAgPT4gYOKCtCIsIjbJvuKAuuKIhm9gZGnDuMKk4bmAwqcg4oaR4bmZIOKCrMeQIMO3wqggwqvDuOKfkcaS4oKE4bitYOKMiHZNxpJKUnbhuYTCuzlUcuKMiMK7YlTEsGDhuo7ihrLCvcS/YHBpIiwiLCIsIiJd)

#### How?

Get the list `["second", "third", ... , "seventh"]`:

```
6ɾ›∆o
```

Get the list `["diminished", "minor", "perfect", "major", "augumented"]`:

```
`diø¤Ṁ§ ↑ṙ €ǐ ÷¨ «ø⟑ƒ₄ḭ`⌈
```

Get all pairs in the correct order and join them by space:

```
vMƒJRvṄ
```

Only keep the some of the pairs:

```
»9Tr⌈»bTİ
```

Prepend `"unison"` and index into the list:

```
`Ẏ↲½Ŀ`pi
```

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), 153 bytes

```javascript
n=>n?(a="AugmentedDiminishedMinorMajorPerfectSecondThirdFourthFifthSixthSeventh".match(/.[a-z]+/g))["51324"[n-9]^n%13%4]+' '+a[n+3*(n>11)+19>>2]:'Unison'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZLRatswFIbv8xQHQ5E0Jy5Ouos22GWw9a5skO7KeCBsOVZxjoqshNGyNxjsZpfbe/R5@gJ7hEyxQhzLN7L1/Tr/OTpHj3zH20LLJzNDVYp9lewxSfGW8iT4sF1vBBpRfpQbibKtRXkvUel7/qj0F6ErUZiVKBSWD7XU5Z3aalPfycrUK/ndLmJno@sg2nBT1PQyyvjsOQ8v14xlwft4Mb8KMpxd59/wIl5cXOUhARLyDMPFO4ppHLMwvk7TeX5DvtrkCsl@mU0AMgjcPoB86vanQuGoTCHoawZXY3@8u8SYHm41or21r5wl6K7v@/uws/dg7@6EYd2uof3pY8tH3Fn7tPc@Kp75YU5@zR48JRziM@dO8Lp9mP2o2R50vR7Cs1YPhcEo3ZsazdLHx2F6@HyaThrW/rkwfCfs@Uk@iSqlP3H7cKm0EXrHmykggySFF2vWCANatJBARZEtLbGvo1WNiBq1phgZtTJa4pqy6ImXK8O1oXMGIZAbIPZziLWb7v@UIJJYNNtStNTKDG6B/Hv99fbnt10J2Li3vz8Js8l@sOX@Pw)

#### How?

The case \$n=0\$ is processed separately.

We use the repeating sequence ***Diminished** / **Minor** / **Major** / **Augmented*** for \$1\le n\le 8\$ and for \$14\le n\le 21\$. The corresponding indices in the lookup array are \$[1,2,3,0]\$. This is done by reducing \$n\$ modulo \$13\$ and then modulo \$4\$.

We actually use the same calculation for \$9\le n\le 13\$, but we apply a bitwise XOR to get the correct indices \$[4,3,0,2,4]\$, corresponding to ***Perfect** (Fourth) / **Major** (Fourth) / **Augmented** (Fourth) / **Minor** (Fifth) / **Perfect** (Fifth)*.

This gives:

```javascript
"51324"[n - 9] ^ n % 13 % 4
```

We then need to append ***Second*** to ***Seventh*** with indices \$5\$ to \$10\$ in the lookup array. The expected sequence is:

```
     n | 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
-------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 index | 5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  8  8  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10
```

Basically, each index is repeated 4 times but 3 indices are omitted between \$n=11\$ and \$n=12\$.

This can be obtained with:

```javascript
n + 3 * (n > 11) + 19 >> 2
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>95</s> 94 bytes

```
⪫Ｅ§⪪”$＆⊞ςq×Ｐ5μ·⸿§▷"↑Ｗ4⪪9Ｑλς”²⊖Ｎ§⪪”↶⌈∨Ｓ⎚χ]¹↶Ｅ´üêＢ⭆↓ＨηW◧⁻◨~,⦄Zi≦r⊗Þπ↖Z):⊕À´Ａeδ∨8:≧#$/ＶMχ)Ａ” ⌕αι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7NTsUgEEZfZdIVTWpi3LqCcumfGhOfAGEqY1poKNzct0eu7tycTObLnG@M09EEvZXyHsknNgfy7FUfjKfJW7yxj2OjxBquhOqVVHwQQz/I4TL2oxzFdJn4LOZ@ljNfxNIvcnlpOnhqO5BoIu7oE1o2@SOnt7x/YmRtW8N/dks7eTodWqhDiLDr70qdv/4EcGBc0SQ40QRvITmKFtaQY3Kw0lp50u1OvNYDB7nagq@fNNDUOkXeMt0B/Zbfd@1zKY/l4br9AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    ”...”                   Compressed lookup table
   ⪪     ²                  Split into substrings of length `2`
  §                         Index by
           Ｎ                Input integer
          ⊖                 Decremented
 Ｅ                          Map over letters
             ⪪”...”         List of words
            §               Indexed by
                    ⌕αι     Uppercase letter index
⪫                           Join with spaces
                            Implicitly print
```

Note that the lookup table is `43` letters long so that the last entry only has one letter; this is the one that is then selected for an input of `0`.

Previous 95-byte solution:

```
Ｎθ∧θ§⪪”↶↧*y³↨Cⅈ～➙…⟧⊖⁺¡κＹ⁸⁴Σ1|R6；” §”)⊞⮌i›‽”θＭ→§⪪”↶⌈∨l⟲Ｅχ⁼⁰θ℅ＢNμ↨%),ρ℅«◨ TＨＹ¬O⬤ε” §”)➙:⌊B/Ｍ⁷ê\`”θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7BasMwDIbvfQrhkwMdJHG2w3LqsYeN0j5BFiu1SmInjhz69q4KgzL2gX6EhPjUuy72oRtzPvo58XeafjDqpWh3p0ie9cFbvezhwEdv8a4v80islaWJPK0OLUgTIkzdTbJL1wk9y3TGOGDPag8KVPG6V01Z1eZZTW0qWS@F0O6@wob680xXxy/1X2cSYfCwYh@8BXYULQwhRXYw0CC50v2ZuMkL7r@5rIRaMMY0zbvwIfy@0OZc5rdtfAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the distance.

```
∧θ§⪪”...” §”...”θ
```

If it's not zero, cyclically index into the compressed table `4012301234231` to find the index into the compressed list of words `diminished minor major augmented perfect`.

```
Ｍ→
```

Leave a space between the two words.

```
§⪪”...” §”...”θ
```

Index into the compressed table `0111122223334455556666` to find the index into the compressed list of words `unison second third fourth fifth sixth seventh`.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>71</s> 70 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.•10°ÝΣËðw¶\ƵUʒ•…‡®¢ÑíÀ«#•”Öζт'µ•5вè“…Þ‰ª¦ƒ³äÇïÖµ“#•γ¤æ•ÅΓø.•I¢#€•šÅв»
```

Outputs in lowercase.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f71HDIkODQxsOzz23@HD34Q3lh7bFHNsaemoSUPxRw7JHDQsPrTu06PDEw2sPNxxarQwWnXt42rltF5vUD20Fck0vbDq84lHDHKDiw/MeNWw4tOrQsmOTDm0@vORw@@H1h6eBFM0B6Tu3@dCSw0ADFx1uPTf58A6QxZ6HFik/aloDZB1deLj1wqZDu///NzIEAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9keGySn72SwqO2SQpK9n7/9R41LDI0OLTh8Nxziw93H95QfmhbzLGtoacmAcUfNSx71LDw0LpDiw5PPLz2cMOh1cpg0bmHp53bdrFJ/dBWINf0wqbDKx41zAEqPjzvUcOGQ6sOLTs26dDmw0sOtx9ef3gaSNEckL5zmw8tOQw0cNHh1nOTD@8AWex5aJHyo6Y1QNbRhYdbL2w6tPu/zn8A).

**Explanation:**

```python
.•10°ÝΣËðw¶\ƵUʒ• # Push compressed string "augmented diminished "
 …‡®¢ÑíÀ         # Push dictionary string "major minor perfect"
        «        # Append them together
         #       # Split this string on spaces:
                 #  ["augmented","diminished","major","minor","perfect"]
•”Öζт'µ•        '# Push compressed integer 160475945053335
        5в       # Convert it to base-5 as list:
                 #  [1,3,2,0,1,3,2,1,4,2,1,3,4,1,3,2,0,1,3,2,0]
          è      # 0-based index each into the previous list of strings
“…Þ‰ª¦ƒ³äÇïÖµ“   # Push dictionary string "second third fourth fifth sixth seventh"
              #  # Split it by spaces as well
•γ¤æ•            # Push compressed integer 4333444
     ÅΓ          # Run-length decode the list of strings and digits of this integer
ø                # Create pairs of the two list of strings
 .•I¢#€•         # Push compressed string "unison"
        š        # Prepend it to the list of pairs
Åв               # Convert the (implicit) input-integer to this custom base as list
  »              # Join each inner pair by spaces, and then the strings by newlines,
                 # which simply pushes the only string in the list in this case
                 # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (all four sections)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `.•10°ÝΣËðw¶\ƵUʒ•` is `"augmented diminished "`; `…‡®¢ÑíÀ` is `"major minor perfect"`; `•”Öζт'µ•` is `160475945053335`; `•”Öζт'µ•5в` is `[1,3,2,0,1,3,2,1,4,2,1,3,4,1,3,2,0,1,3,2,0]`; `“…Þ‰ª¦ƒ³äÇïÖµ“` is `"second third fourth fifth sixth seventh"`; `•γ¤æ•` is `4333444`; and `.•I¢#€•` is `"unison"`.